# iron-ajax (Polymer 1.0) on-response event firing twice

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Has anyone encountered iron-ajax's on-response event firing twice for a single request?  I have double-checked, and I am in fact submitting a single request.  Here is my iron-ajax implementation (just an element that wraps iron-ajax):

```
<dom-module id="my-ajax">

    <template>
        <iron-ajax id="ajax" auto="{{auto}}" url="{{url}}" method="{{method}}" headers="{{headers}}" body="{{body}}" handle-as="json" content-type="application/json" on-response="responseHandler" on-error="errorHandler" with-credentials></iron-ajax>
    </template>

</dom-module>
```

```
// Register the polymer element
Polymer({

    is: 'my-ajax',

    properties: {
        actionDesc: {type: String, value: ""},
        auto: {type: Boolean, value: false},
        body: {type: String, value: null},
        headers: {type: Object, value: null},
        isBusy: {
            // One-way binding setup (i.e. child to host only)
            type: Boolean,
            value: false,
            readOnly: true,
            notify: true
        },
        method: {type: String, value: null},
        user: {type: Object, value: null},
        url: {type: String, value: null}
    },

    generateRequest: function() {
        if (!this.isBusy) {
            // Execute request as it isn't currently busy processing a previous request
            this.isBusy = true;

            this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
        } else {
            // TODO: Queue up this request
        }
    },

    responseHandler: function(e, detail) {
        console.log(this.id + " responseHandler fired!\n"); 
        this.isBusy = false;
        this.fire("handle-response", detail.xhr.response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer:**

I think you should remove the `auto` attribute and its binding from your `<iron-ajax>` declaration as follows:

```
<iron-ajax id="ajax" url="{{url}}" method="{{method}}"
           headers="{{headers}}" body="{{body}}" handle-as="json"
           content-type="application/json"
           on-response="responseHandler"
           on-error="errorHandler" with-credentials></iron-ajax>
```

---

I think the problem is in the "`auto`" property, [Polymer´s documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) shows an example like this:

```
<iron-ajax
    auto
    url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
    params='{"alt":"json", "q":"chrome"}'
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"
    debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>
```

And the documentation says:

> `auto` {`Boolean`} default: `false`
>
> If true, automatically performs an Ajax request when either url or params changes.

So, I think when you add the "`auto`" attribute, its value is automatically set true by default, even if you bind it. That's why I think you should remove it.

Sorry for my English, I hope you can understand me.

Comment: Yes, the auto property (although it is bound to a value that is false), seems to cause the problem.  Upon removal of that attribute, the on-response event only fires once.  Thanks!  Is this by design?  It doesn't seem to me that this should occur if it is bound to boolean false.

Comment: @sinjins I think you must know if your ajax request must be Automatically generated (add "auto" property) or not (don't add "auto" property), anyway, maybe something like "this.$.IdIronAjax.auto = false" should work to set "auto" property as false.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Flavio Ochoa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31617434/2740692), the `auto` attribute, if true, will make the `iron-ajax` perform the request automatically if the *url* or *params* changes.

To make the binding work how you want it to without making the call twice, your binding should have `$` before the `=`  on the `auto` attribute like so:

```
<iron-ajax 
   id="ajax" 
   auto$="{{auto}}" 
   url="{{url}}" 
   method="{{method}}" 
   headers="{{headers}}" 
   body="{{body}}" 
   handle-as="json" 
   content-type="application/json" 
   on-response="responseHandler" 
   on-error="errorHandler" 
   with-credentials>
</iron-ajax>
```

From the [Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding), the auto attribute if bound like this will only be set if the binding value is truthy

A little late to the party but, hope this helps someone